# How to change object which is passed down to child component with one-way-binding

Tags: angularjs, components

I'm working with AngularJS 1.6 and a component based web application. I'm building a new component which contains a table and on selecting a row another stateless component is being displayed with detailed information about that rows' object (the row is passe down via '<'-binding). So far, it works. I'm using stateful and stateless components, and from Todd Motto I learned to use one way binding (also in preparation to migrate to Angular) and that to break JavaScripts' bind-by-reference I should use following event hook in the stateless component (the detail component in my specific case):

```
ctrl.$onChange = function(changes) {
    if (changes.row) {
        this.row = angular.copy(this.row);
    }
};
```

It does work in the sense that changes in the child component do not change the object in the parent component anymore, cause the bind-by-reference is broken.

**Problem is**: If I select another row in the table, the changed object is NOT being passed down anymore, the stateless component does not "recognize" a changed object in the binding! If I ommit the above code it works, but will it still work when migrating to Angular? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the changes:

```
ctrl.$onChange = function(changes) {
    if (changes.row) {
        ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶r̶o̶w̶ ̶=̶ ̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶c̶o̶p̶y̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶r̶o̶w̶)̶;̶
        this.row = angular.copy(changes.row.currentValue);
    }
};
```

From the Docs:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as **cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value**. Note that this will also be called when your bindings are initialized.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)